# How to connect IBM websphere MQ v 7.0 using java code

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am unable to connect IBM websphere MQ 
Can anyone tell me what are the initial setting need to be done in MQ to acces it from remote machine using simple java code?

Comment: Get the IBM documentation and MQ JARs, create a client, and make a connection.  http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/MQ%20tutorial.%20MQ%20Intercommunication.%20Queue%20Local%20and%20Queue%20Remote%20example!opendocument

Comment: Look at the samples shipped with MQ. There are number of Java samples shipped with MQ.

Comment: @Shashi  can help me with this code.. i am  totally new to this concept..Like just the connection with Quemanager

Comment: @duffymo it is licensed software

Comment: I'm assuming you have a licensed copy.  Otherwise what would be the point of your question?  If not, you should be learning JMS on an open source Java EE app server like JBOSS or Glassfish.   Are you incapable of reading documentation?

Comment: What have you done so far? Any sample code to post?

Comment: @Shashi int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
         MQEnvironment.hostname = "10.60.1.35";
         MQEnvironment.port = 7004;
         MQEnvironment.channel = "TEBTCHNL";
         MQQueueManager qMgr;
         try {
             qMgr = new MQQueueManager("TEBT");
             MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("ZAG_RESPONSE", openOptions);
             System.out.println("Queue size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());
             destQueue.close();
             qMgr.disconnect();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

Comment: Code looks OK to me. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the MQ samples shipped with the product, there is also a long list of Java & Java/JMS samples [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html).

The recommended practice for MQ Java (non-JMS) is:

```
Hashtable mqht = new Hashtable();
mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(portNumber));
try
{
   MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
   System.out.println("Successfully connected to "+ qMgrName);
}
catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex)
{
   System.out.println("MQException cc=" +mqex.completionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.reasonCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points to make sure you are able to connect to Websphere MQ using Java code :

1. Have you validated your MQ server deployment using these steps "Verifying Installation" in following deployment instructions http://sadockobeth.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-install-ibm-websphere-mq-75-on.html
2. Have you started a listener for a Queue Manager that is configured on your MQ server. You can find command to start Listener here http://bencane.com/2013/04/22/websphere-mq-cheat-sheet-for-system-administrators/
3. With default installation the connection from a Java application over TCP will fail because of channel authentication enforced by default. You can confirm this is the case by looking at Queue manager error logs. Would suggest you to look at appropriate ways to configure channel authentication to allow the Java application to connect. One method ok for *Non-Production* or *test set up* is to disable channel (Please use this with caution).
4. If all of the above are taken care and still you are not able to connect than you will need to look at your Java client code and get more information from error codes that your code is seeing. If there are any genuine network connectivity issues or some thing else like firewall preventing connection etc.